# Neural nets for novices

Tags: neural-networks

Stories like [this](https://aiweirdness.com/post/185339301987/once-again-a-neural-net-tries-to-name-cats) one are quite popular these days.

The idea of training a neural net to do something silly like this may sound trivial to experts like you,  but for a novice like me it could be an interesting learning experience.

Is there novice-friendly software I could play with to train a neural net to do something like this or is there necessarily a steep learning curve?

Comment: You can take a look at PyTorch an open source deep learning platform which in my opinion is very easy to get started with, especially if you're familiar with programming in python.

Answer (score 3):

An intuitive NN playground can be found in [TensorFlow Playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org)

Also, check the Google ML crash course for coders as they promised to add more [practicals](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/practica/).

Answer (score 2):

keras is probably the highest level and easiest to go into.
Here are some [keras tutorials](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python/)